# Converting URI.getQueryParams to hashmap

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a requirement where I need to get URI.getQueryParams in map, Currently this method returns MultiValueMap , will there be a good way to do that?

Comment: `MultiValueMap<K, V>` is a `Map<K, List<V>>`. Where's your actual problem?

Comment: In my code I have a condition where I will be either getting fragment or queryParams , now when I get Fragments I can create a map out of it , but if I get queryParams , I get multivalued map , and the logic which I need to use after getting respective map is same, but as of now I am not able to use it.

Comment: Why can't you use this `MultiValueMap`?